# Is there any program similar to WireframeSketcher that is available and free for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm developing a mobile application and such a program would be useful for me.
I found [WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com/) on Ubuntu Software Center, but it doens't seem free since I have to fill payment details.

Comment: Are you looking for something that integrates with Eclipse, like WireframeSketcher? Or is that not a requirement?

Comment: That is not a requirement. I am open to both types. The application I'm developing is for android and Wireframesketcher has already available a gallery of components fpr android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pencil is a firefox plugin which might suit your needs: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pencil/

[image]

Comment: +1 You can run it standalone too. See http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/Home.aspx for the projects home page and check out the screenshots: http://pencil.evolus.vn/en-US/ScreenShots.aspx

Comment: Might be worth editing your answer to include a screenshot which will help show what it is like.

Comment: Ok, that seems good to me! thank you! Can I upload my own images? And can I upload Android componets library?

Comment: Actually: 'Not available for Firefox 13.0'

Comment: I downloaded the standalone version 'Pencil-1.3-4-fx.xpi'. I am now trying to install it or open it...How does it work?
I tried the following instructions: 'http://webtoolsandtips.com/firefox-addon/install-xpi-firefox-addons/' but foud no such button

Comment: Ok, i dragged the *.xpi fili into Firefox and I installed it.Done! thank you!

Comment: I don't want to install firefox, which means I can't use this app.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Dia from [Ubuntu Software Center](http://www.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/features/ubuntu-software-centre) ?

```
sudo apt-get install dia
```

Comment: I tried Dia once and found it tedious to work with it for wireframing purposes